# Firebase Data Loss?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

I occasionally discover fields in Firebase that have been cleared out and I've looked but I can't find a way in the Google Cloud Console that shows X data was modified by X user at X date and time. Am I missing something??

Comment: You should contact Firebase support, I've once had a problem with accessing my Firebase project for deployment, and it has been resolved in 3 days

Comment: @ceejayoz While that is indeed a very similar question, the answer is outdated. Nowadays Cloud Firestore *does* offer audit logs, although it is disabled by default. See https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/audit-logging (I also added an answer to the link)